# Can a reverse proxy to an application web service be set up in IIS on the same server as the web service?

Tags: reverse-proxy

I have a public-facing reverse proxy server for a web service on an internal server and we are replacing the internal server with Windows Server 2022 and want to eliminate the separate proxy server and add this functionality to the new internal server directly.  I can add an additional NIC to the new server on the external subnet but can I add the proxy site in IIS and use Application Request Routing to proxy requests to the web service site on this same server?

Comment: You could (by specifically binding proxy and application to different IP addresses or even ports), but I would *never* use an IIS as reverse proxy towards the public 'net.

Comment: @Zac67 - It would sit behind our main firewall so would you still not use IIS for this purpose?  How could it be better set up on the same server, even if it requires using additional software?